# A doubt regarding the usage of definite article

Tags: definite-article, british-english

I came across this sentence the other day and I would appreciate a clarification:

> Prepared specially for **the students** of university of Kerala, this book will also be invaluable to **students** and teachers of English grammar across the country.

In the first part of the sentence the usage of *the* is understandable (which according to me the word *students* is specified by *of the university of Kerala*), but in the second part of the sentence, even though *students and teachers* is made specific by *of English grammar across the country*, the article *the* is not used.

Comment: The only explanation is that 'students of English grammar' is not specific _enough_ to require the definite article.

Comment: I would say further that the article is correct, but not required, in both phrases. Just in case you're interested, I've noticed that many people from India use the word 'doubt' to mean 'question'. One gets used to it after dealing with enough people from the country, but it can be slightly confusing otherwise. It would be more natural to say "A question regarding...".

Comment: thank you @rcook

Comment: I would add that at least in US English it should be "**the** University of Kerala". I am not sure about the usage in Indian English.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say "university of Kerala" is a rather confined concept, whereas "English grammar across the country." is much broader.